# Android: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I still got a crash report because of this Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I have searched about it, still can't figure it out how to fix this.

I have using Theme.AppCompat.Light as base AppTheme. Here my style.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/toolbar</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/toolbar_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverFlow</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/ActionBarSearchView</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/switch_activated</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/switch_normal</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/switch_track</item>
</style>
```

I only have 1 style.xml inside values folder

I'm using crashlytics in my app, I got this problem only from some device, but this is really annoys me.

Is there anyone know hot to fix this?

**I have done both of things below, but still got a crash report.**

Comment: Change to `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">` and ensure you have set in AndroidManifest.xml the theme as `@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: Just changed it, but is there any differences between them?

Comment: @user2341387: so, any progress with this ?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this problem because you have derived one or more of your `Activity` classes from `ActionBarActivity`. You need to either derive from `Activity` **OR** you need to use one of the `Theme.Appcompat` styles for your `ActionBar`. And make sure you specify the correct `android:theme` attribute in all your `<activity ... />` declarations in your manifest.

**EDIT:**

Add `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` to the declaration of `MainActivity` in your app manifest. And change `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"` to `parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"` in `res/theme.xml`.

Comment: I only have 1 MainActivity and already extends ActionBarActivity. I have checked and make sure everything written correctly.

Comment: Done both of things above, let's see if it will fixed

Comment: @user2341387: are you still having a problem with this answer ?

Comment: Yes, still got force close report

Comment: but the answer is correct ... it works ... the bug has to be due to another reason ... what is the error that was reported ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. Like written above,

Comment: then it means that you have not written android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in the manifest for one or more of your Activitys, because the answer is correct ...

Comment: I have done it, android:theme="@style/AppTheme" in both application and activity tag

Comment: Like I said, I still got force close report

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem for me either. Using Robolectric 3.0 and target SDK version 22, with Theme.AppCompat set as the activity's theme.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either.  The OP can't mark it as solved if it doesn't do the job.  Is this still a problem user2341387 ?